# Add fragment to abstract activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I'm trying to add a fragment to an abstract activity. This is a base activity and all other activities in my app extend from it.

My problem: when I add the fragment to base activity it gives me the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09011d (com.musicplayer.musicana:id/nowPlayingScreensContainer) for fragment SlidingUpPanelFragment{961e486 #0 id=0x7f09011d}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using the framelayout's id present in base activity while adding the fragment.

XML of baseActivity:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout

    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="70dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="10dp"
    android:background="#000"
    sothree:umanoFadeColor="#b2000000"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />


    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/nowPlayingScreensContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>




</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

There are two framelayouts in this, first one for adding activities and second for adding fragments.

Code for adding fragments(written in onCreate):

```
 SlidingUpPanelFragment fragment = SlidingUpPanelFragment.newInstance();
         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nowPlayingScreensContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Full log:

```
Failed to capture application
06-21 14:54:22.002 2601-2601/com.musicplayer.musicana E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f09011d (com.musicplayer.musicana:id/nowPlayingScreensContainer) for fragment SlidingUpPanelFragment{961e486 #0 id=0x7f09011d}
    Activity state:
06-21 14:54:22.014 2601-2601/com.musicplayer.musicana E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.musicplayer.musicana, PID: 2601
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.musicplayer.musicana/com.musicplayer.musicana.splash}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09011d (com.musicplayer.musicana:id/nowPlayingScreensContainer) for fragment SlidingUpPanelFragment{961e486 #0 id=0x7f09011d}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2699)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f09011d (com.musicplayer.musicana:id/nowPlayingScreensContainer) for fragment SlidingUpPanelFragment{961e486 #0 id=0x7f09011d}
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1422)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6701)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2662)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

OnCreate of base activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);



        slidingUpPanelLayout = findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
        slidingUpPanelLayout.addPanelSlideListener(this);
        storageUtil = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());

        pref = getSharedPreferences(TAG,MODE_PRIVATE);
        registerSelectScreenReceiver();

         SlidingUpPanelFragment fragment = SlidingUpPanelFragment.newInstance();
         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.nowPlayingScreensContainer, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


        }
```

Will be glad to provide more codes. How to solve this?

Comment: Where is the log refer in your code ? or can you show the fully log ?

Comment: yeah,sure,just a second.

Comment: Posted. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I got it, but its not have lot of information, so where you adding fragments ?

Comment: In the onCreate of base activity. It is already posted.

Comment: yep, but can you show more ?

Comment: Do you want me to show the fragment class? Because I think I have posted everything except that.

Comment: I guest your issue occur because you adding fragment before init your activity layout, so can you provide code in onCreate() of your activity ?

Comment: Updated. Please take a look.

Comment: I try to run your code and every thing is ok, so I think the reason not about your code, do you try to clean your project ?

Comment: Actually I did some debugging and found that all the activities that extend base activity should add their layout to the base activity container else the above mentioned exception will be given. I don't know why this happens.